# SiteDefinition Config Events - Site Changed to MyCompanyName

Tags: events, site-configuration

I noticed a strange difference between our Production and QA Sitecore websites that was deliberately done by our Sitecore vendor.

In the `SiteDefinition.config` file, the site block is changed to MyCompanyName.

Why would this be different? Can I change the one on QA to match Production or will that break something?

**QA:**

```
<events>
  <event name="publish:end">
    <handler type="Sitecore.Publishing.HtmlCacheClearer, Sitecore.Kernel" method="ClearCache">
      <sites hint="list">
        <site>MyCompanyName</site>
      </sites>
    </handler>
  </event>
  <event name="publish:end:remote">
    <handler type="Sitecore.Publishing.HtmlCacheClearer, Sitecore.Kernel" method="ClearCache">
      <sites hint="list">
        <site>MyCompanyName</site>
      </sites>
    </handler>
  </event>
</events>
```

**PROD:**

```
    <events>
  <event name="publish:end">
    <handler type="Sitecore.Publishing.HtmlCacheClearer, Sitecore.Kernel" method="ClearCache">
      <sites hint="list">
        <MyCompanyName>MyCompanyName</MyCompanyName>
      </sites>
    </handler>
  </event>
  <event name="publish:end:remote">
    <handler type="Sitecore.Publishing.HtmlCacheClearer, Sitecore.Kernel" method="ClearCache">
      <sites hint="list">
        <MyCompanyName>MyCompanyName</MyCompanyName>
      </sites>
    </handler>
  </event>
</events>
```

Comment: Do you have any configuration transformations applied during building to your QA and Production environments, that changes the config files (possibly differently)?

Comment: Actually, that is exactly what I am working on right now. We are using Octopus Deploy and I want to correct this if I can, because it seems odd.

Comment: i would ask that you do basic research around your question before posting. If you need assistance and interactive debugging, Slack is a better medium.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works because of the way that `HtmlCacheClear` processes the `<sites>` list.

When you take a peek into the code for `HtmlCacheClearer.ClearCache()` method, you'll see that it's iterating through the list of sites in a basic `for()` loop.  Therefore, the element name of the list item makes no difference whatsoever.

As for how it changed to **MyCompanyName** in prod, I have no idea.  Bad transform file? Either way, it doesn't matter.

You will be safe changing it on QA.

```cs
/// <summary>Clears the cache.</summary>
/// <param name="sender">The sender.</param>
/// <param name="args">The arguments.</param>
public void ClearCache(object sender, EventArgs args)
{

   ...

  for (int index = 0; index < this._sites.Count; ++index)
  {
    string siteName = this._sites[index] as string;

   ...

  }
   ...
}
```

Comment: The change was deliberately done by our vendor.

Comment: I've seen it before and I think it was done to not overwrite other values in the "list" when patching it. But as Pete says, it does not matter..